# IDE error when trying to add symbols in 'id in R'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

"toolbar", "name" and "press" on R.id are all red and can't be found. I've reinstalled the application.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mNameText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.press);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            handleButtonClick();
        }
    });
}

private void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar toolbar) {
}
private void handleButtonClick() {
    mNameText.setText("The button was clicked");
}
```

I get IDE error when I try to create a field for them in 'id in R'.

Answer (score 0):

`R` is a generated class when you build your application. You can not add fields in it directly. Share your full Activity and its XML file so we could help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, be sure that the "name", "press" and "toolbar" are the ids of the corresponding elements in your activity_main.xml file.

If that is already in order, sometimes just rebuilding the project can fix this error. 
From the Android Studio toolbar go to Build -> Clean Project. After that's done do Build -> Rebuild Project.

Comment: Thanks for that now I understand it, quite new to this